# fix Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is  my connection string:

```
  Dim connSQLServerMaster As New SqlConnection("Data Source=YOUSRY\LAB_SERVER;Initial Catalog=master;User ID=admin;Password=123")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Restore database clinic_program from disk ='d:\backup\clinic_program.bak' with Replace,recovery", connSQLServerMaster)
        connSQLServerMaster.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       connSQLServerMaster.Close()
    end sub
```

When trying to access the DB there is an error:

> Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A restore can only happen if the database does not have any connections to it (besides yours). The easy way on a MS SQL Server to kick all users off is:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate
GO
```

Now, you can perform your restore with impunity. Make sure you set it back to Multi-user mode when you're done with the restore:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET Multi_User
GO
```